# Setting checkbox input checked value based on checked state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, state

I can successfully add in the value and checked state of an input to a state array, so when I click on an input, the value and checked state get pushed to the array, and when I click it again, the value and checked state from that specific input is taken out of the array.

Where I'm stuck is if I go to the next step/component, then go back, I'm trying to have my input set it's checked state based on whether or not it's already in the state array.

There's three inputs, they default to unchecked. I'll click on #1 and #3, hit the next button, go to the next step, hit the back button, now all three inputs are back to unchecked even though the state still has #1 and #3 in it. I'd like #1 and #3 to show up as checked.

```
const [addon, setAddon] = useState([]); //This is in another file

function AddOns({ addon, setAddon }) {
    const checkHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked === true) {
            setAddon([
                ...addon,
                { value: e.target.value, checked: e.target.checked },
            ]);
        }

        if (e.target.checked === false) {
            const nextAddon = addon.filter((a) => a.value !== e.target.value);
            setAddon(nextAddon);
        }
    };
                <Input
                    value="Online service"
                    dataAmount="+$1/mo"
                    dataNumber="1"
                    // checked={}
                    addonDetail="Access to multiplayer games"
                    onClick={(e) => checkHandler(e)}
                />
                {/* <!-- Add on --> */}
                <Input
                    value="Larger storage"
                    dataAmount="+$2/mo"
                    dataNumber="2"
                    // checked={}
                    addonDetail="Extra 1TB of cloud save"
                    onClick={(e) => checkHandler(e)}
                />
                {/* <!-- Add on --> */}
                <Input
                    value="Customizable profile"
                    dataAmount="+$2/mo"
                    dataNumber="2"
                    // checked={}
                    addonDetail=" Custome theme on your profile"
                    onClick={(e) => checkHandler(e)}
                />
```

I thought maybe looping through the state array to match an array value to the input value and pull the checked state out if it matches might work but I haven't been successful there. I also managed to get the checked attribute set to if there's a checked state as true in the state array, but it would set all three inputs to checked instead of the specific input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#some` to check for a match.

```js
<Input value="Online service"
       checked={addon.some(a => a.value === "Online service")} 
       // other props...
/>
```

Comment: Wow, that was way simpler than what I was trying to do haha, thanks!